# TestNG expectedExceptions handling: Have my cake as well as eat it?

Tags: java, selenium, exception, testng

How to handle expectedExceptions in TestNG such that the test is a pass no matter exception is thrown or not thrown by the code within the test method

I have testng test method which creates a list of certain objects. In a for loop for each of this object a certain action is performed. This action may or may not throw a exception. How to use @Test(expectedExceptions) such that the overall test result is a pass no matter exception is thrown or not.
As per my understanding expectedExceptions will always look for a exception. If exception is found it is handled by Testng and the test result is pass. If exception is not found or a different exception is thrown then the test is failed

```
public class DemoException {
@Test(expectedExceptions = {ConnectException.class})
public void testException() throws ConnectException
  {
    //pseudo code......   
    //create a List<WebElement> myList
    int count = 0;
    for(WebElemet we: myList){
     we.connect(); //this may or may not throw exception
     we.getResponseMessage(); // further actions on we is needed
     we.disconnect();
     //above 3 are HttpURLConnection methods to be precise
     // Basically do - connect, getResponse, disconnect  

 System.out.println(count++); 
     // print count is needed - exception thrown or not thrown
  }
 }
}
```

Expected: The test method should pass no matter exception is thrown or not.
The count value should be printed even if exception is thrown

Actual result: The test method passes (exception is thrown) but the count value is not printed.
If any try-catch logic is added then the count value is printed but test method fails. Which is not what I want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you try this:

```
@Test(expectedExceptions = Exception.class)
public void MyTest() throws Exception {
    int count = 0;
    try {
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {

            throw new Exception("Fake Exception");
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        System.out.println(count++);
        throw  ex;
    }
}
```

Print the count to the log / console and then throw the exception again.

Answer (score 0):

After referring to this [post](https://developers.perfectomobile.com/display/TT/testNG+-+changing+test+results+dynamically), 
I was able to explicitly "modify" the TestNG's result status by implementing IInvokedMethodListener - override afterInvocation method. The test result was a pass.

Answer (score 0):

Try SoftAssert.It will contiue even if test fasils https://static.javadoc.io/org.testng/testng/6.13/org/testng/asserts/SoftAssert.html